# BigQuery query doesn't work with UNNEST()

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to search on StackOverflow data through BigQuery by letting this query match a string pattern on answers and by filtering relevant question answers by tags.

```
WITH question_answers_join AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT id, creation_date, title
      , (SELECT AS STRUCT body b
         FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` 
         WHERE a.id=parent_id
      ) answers
      , SPLIT(tags, '|') tags
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` a
  )
)SELECT * 
FROM question_answers_join
WHERE 'google-bigquery' IN UNNEST(tags)
AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(answers.b, r"hello")
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 100
```

however, I get this error:

> Scalar subquery produced more than one element

what is it referring to? How can I fix this?

Comment: Depends if you are using the legacy mode or the standard mode. ou can't use unnest.

Comment: @Danizavtz is legacy mode the old one? I've now set it, but `WITH` is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH question_answers_join AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT id, creation_date, title
      , ARRAY(SELECT body                             /* this line was the reason for error */
         FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` 
         WHERE a.id=parent_id
      ) answers
      , SPLIT(tags, '|') tags
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` a
  )
)
SELECT *
FROM question_answers_join 
WHERE 'google-bigquery' IN UNNEST(tags)
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM UNNEST(answers) answer 
  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(answer, r"hello")
)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 100
```

I think, it is easy to just compare above with your original query to see the differences (hint: there are just two of them). First difference is the actual reason for the error you saw. Second difference is to reflect changes introduced by first one

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works. I have a question since I've seen your profile and I think you are a Google BigQuery developer (or generally talking, a Google Developer Expert in Cloud). I know Google Big Query is an availment of resources for Google, but why doesn't Google make it free for students (I am one)? It may be expensive for us depending on how many resources we searching for.

Comment: You can check [Google Cloud Platform Free Tier](https://cloud.google.com/free). Also wanted to mention - I am not with Google or anyhow affiliated with Google rather than being a huge fan of BigQuery and recognized by community as a Google Developer Expert and being here on SO daily to help users like you :o)

Comment: Oh yeah, I've got it. "Google Developer Expert" is a bit misleading though, haha. Thank you.

Comment: Sure. Check also [Using the BigQuery sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox) . You also can check https://developers.google.com/community/experts for more about Experts Program! :o)

Comment: Can I query things like this we've just talked about here, but with Sandbox? Concretely talking, what's difference to my (trial?) plan? I still have 19 further projects I can create in my account for querying. Regarding Google Experts Program, let me guess: you are one of it! Haha.